# How to create a Record<> (or other mapping) in TypeScript keyed to an enum as a union

Tags: typescript, enums

I need to create function maps keyed to an enum, but if I use the Record<> utility type, it seems that it's requiring *all* of the enum values to exist in the mapping object.  I need them to all be optional.  For example:

```
enum ContentType {
  Text,
  Image,
  Video,
}
type MapFn = (value: string) => string;

type ContentTypeMap = Record<ContentType, MapFn>;

const myMap = {
  [ContentType.Text] : (value:string) => (value.toUpperCase),
} as ContentTypeMap;
```

Results in:

```
Conversion of type '{ 0: (value: string) => () => string; }' to type 'ContentTypeMap' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ 0: (value: string) => () => string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ContentTypeMap': 1, 2
```

I also tried simply:

```
type ContentMap = { [ContentType]: MapFn };
```

But the compiler complains about the use of ContentType:

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
```

I would think that enums count as literals, but I guess not in this case?

What can I use to create a map of `(enum) => (function)` where the object does not require all enum values to be implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I also tried simply:
>
> ```
> type ContentMap = { [ContentType]: MapFn };
> ```

You're close, but it needs to be like this:

```
type ContentMap = { [key in ContentType]: MapFn };
```

And then to make them optional:

```
type ContentMap = { [key in ContentType]?: MapFn };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9iALqRAVAngB2FA3gWACgopVgAPRAGiJIEkIBDAc2BuKgDUBLAE2DjsAvkURYcAWUaYAYiCgBeKAAoAbowA2YYAC4oAZ0QAnbiGYBKRQD4Dx08wDcRUeNgJkSKZkV4oAbQBrYHQoUzckFAxsAF0Afj0vOSghJ0IiAGMEQygIdC89eAjPaR8CDj9CjzRxADoySmioPTVNbR1DEzNLBRt1LWAaxDgAVUxsIxhGfWBlc2EHIA)

If you prefer to use the Record notation, you can use the utility type [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to make all its properties optional:

```
type ContentMap = Partial<Record<ContentType, MapFn>>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9iALqRAVAngB2FA3gWACgopVgAPRAGiJIEkIBDAc2BuKgDUBLAE2DjsAvkURYcAWUaYAYiCgBeKAAoAbowA2YYAC4oAZ0QAnbiGYBKRQD4Dx08wDcRUeNgJkSKZkVQACoyNEbk0AHgAlYABjOCNeEPgkFAxsKigvOSsrJ0IiaJBDKAh0Lz0Ej0QvHwIOAG0ypPEAOjJKAF0oPTVNbR1DEzNLBRt1LWBGxDgAVUxsIxhGfWBlc2EHIA)

Comment: Cheers, mate, this is what I needed!